# ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial views/jobs/_index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[],

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Im new to ruby, and this error keeps popping up and im not sure what it means.

Heres the code :

```
<% if current_user %>
 <%= link_to 'Sign Out' , destroy_user_session_path , method: :delete %>
 <%= render partial: "views/jobs/index" %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to 'Sign Up' , new_user_registration_path %>
<%= link_to 'Sign In' , new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

my problem is with the rendering. im trying to render a html.haml file from a html.erb file. is this possible?
if it is then this is what im getting :

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial views/jobs/_index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/farah/Desktop/rubyApp/jobapp/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.3.4/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.3.4/app/views"
):
    1: <% if current_user %>
    2:  <%= link_to 'Sign Out' , destroy_user_session_path , method: :delete %>
    3:  <%= render partial: "views/jobs/index" %>
    4: <% else %>
    5: <%= link_to 'Sign Up' , new_user_registration_path %>
    6: <%= link_to 'Sign In' , new_user_session_path %>
```

Comment: update :  `<%= render partial: "jobs/index" %>` still get , `Missing partial jobs/_index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/farah/Desktop/rubyApp/jobapp/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.3.4/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.3.4/app/views"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= render partial: "views/jobs/index" %>
```

Remove the "views" prefix, it's added automatically. You can see it from your error message:

```
Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/farah/Desktop/rubyApp/jobapp/app/views"
```

As you can see, this already includes "views".

Your render statement should be

```
<%= render partial: "jobs/index" %>
```

Rendering haml from within erb is not an issue as long as it's configured correctly and your error message says it is correct:

```
:handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder, :haml]
```

Handlers includes `:haml`, so it will work.

Comment: actually even when changing the render statement  :   ` <% if current_user %>
` <%= link_to 'Sign Out' , destroy_user_session_path , method: :delete %>`
 `<%= render partial: "jobs/index" %>`
`<% else %>`
`<%= link_to 'Sign Up' , new_user_registration_path %>`
`<%= link_to 'Sign In' , new_user_session_path %>`
`<% end %>`
     i still get the same error

Comment: where is the view you're trying to render? Is it `app/views/jobs/_index.haml`? Or is it something else?

Comment: yes , its  ```app/views/jobs/_index.haml```

Comment: actually the (_) was missing. Once it was placed, i could access the view. But for some reason the each in my jobs is showed as ```ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: #jobs
    2: - @jobs.each do |job|
    3:   .job
    4:     %h2= link_to job.title , job
    5:     %p= job.company```